# How to implement browser-based client for MMO (using Java, LWJGL and LibGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, browser, lwjgl

I apologize in advance for what might be a terrible question... We are developing a MMO using mostly using LibGDX. Kryonet is being used for networking, and rendering is done using LibGDX functions. The current client seems to be a LwjglApplication, and I want to make it so that the game is playable using a web browser. It seems like I can implement it as a Java applet or using this GWT thing. What would be the easiest and most bug-free thing to implement for a novice such as I? (Links to tutorials especially welcome).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with lwjgl applet. But I want to warn you that you should think twice if you actually want your game to be played through browser - if you want to look reliable, you have to sign your jars, which cost around 200$ / year.

Comment: I am not planning on publishing it to the general public, then in that case will it still cost money?

Comment: No, of course not. With unsigned jar you will have to 1) reduce security settings to minimum, because else it will be blocked and 2) you will always get a window asking if you really trust the jar from unknown publisher.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use GWT then I recommend you to consider PlayN https://github.com/threerings/playn